# unzip32.dll change my file privilege

Tags: vb6, unzip, privileges

i'm programming in VB6. 
Then i need decompress a zip file using unzip32.dll. This zip file only have a .exe file.
The file is uncompressed overwriting the old exe file. My problem is in the new .exe because the old privileges are missing and now i can't execute it.

```
Public Declare Function Wiz_SingleEntryUnzip Lib "unzip32.dll" (ByVal ifnc As Long, ByRef ifnv As ZIPnames, ByVal xfnc As Long, ByRef xfnv As ZIPnames, dcll As DCLIST, Userf As USERFUNCTION) As Long
```

Why?? Any suggestions?

Thanks

My code:

```
Dim Resultado As Long
Dim intContadorFicheros As Integer

Dim FuncionesUnZip As UNZIPUSERFUNCTION
Dim OpcionesUnZip As UNZIPOPTIONS

Dim NombresFicherosZip As ZIPnames, NombresFicheros2Zip As ZIPnames

NombresFicherosZip.S(0) = vbNullChar
NombresFicheros2Zip.S(0) = vbNullChar
FuncionesUnZip.UNZIPMessage = 0&
FuncionesUnZip.UNZIPPassword = 0&
FuncionesUnZip.UNZIPPrntFunction = DevolverDireccionMemoria(AddressOf FuncionParaProcesarMensajes)
FuncionesUnZip.UNZIPReplaceFunction = DevolverDireccionMemoria(AddressOf FuncionParaReplaceOptions)
FuncionesUnZip.UNZIPService = 0&
FuncionesUnZip.UNZIPSndFunction = 0&
OpcionesUnZip.C_flag = 1
OpcionesUnZip.fQuiet = 2
OpcionesUnZip.noflag = 1
OpcionesUnZip.Zip = Zip
OpcionesUnZip.ExtractDir = ExtractDir

Resultado = Wiz_SingleEntryUnzip(0, NombresFicherosZip, 0, NombresFicheros2Zip, OpcionesUnZip, FuncionesUnZip)
```

This code, unzip a miprograma.exe file inside the zip file. Then overwrite a existing exe file. But now i can't run it because the privileges of a miprograma.exe file is missing.

Comment: Can you please add information to the question which clearly states the error or other problem you are having?

Comment: Thanks DaveInCaz. Now I explain better the problem.